# Assigning string to purrr::pluck function

Tags: r, tidyverse, purrr

I am trying to write a helper function for a purrr::pluck() to enframe() code that I have too many times written out, but I am struggling with how to pass the pluck call correctly.

Here is an example of the written code I am trying to put into a function.

```
json_data %>%
    purrr::pluck("Leagues", 1, "Events") %>%
    enframe(name = NULL, value = "data")
```

Here is the function

```
get_tibble <- function(data, pluck, name = NULL, value = "value") {
  clean_tibble <- data %>%
    purrr::pluck(pluck) %>%
    enframe(name = name, value = value)

  return(clean_tibble)
}
```

But when I pass c("Leagues", 1, "Events") to the pluck function, it doesn't work. It looks like its because when it passes the number 1 it is quoting it, but im not sure how to pass it without that.

Heres an example

```
    get_tibble <- function(data, pluck, name = NULL, value = "value") {
      clean_tibble <- data %>%
        purrr::pluck(pluck) %>%
        enframe(name = name, value = value)
      
      return(clean_tibble)
    }
    
    json_data <- list(
      ResponseTime = "0s",
      OddsType = "american",
      Leagues = list(
        list(
          LeagueId = 889,
          SportID = 15,
          IsLive = FALSE,
          HasLiveLines = FALSE,
          Events = list(
            data = NULL
          ),
          EventCount = 1
        )
      )
    )
    
    ##This works
clean_tibble <- json_data %>%
      purrr::pluck("Leagues", 1, "Events") %>%
      enframe(name = NULL, value = "data")
    
    ##This doesn't
clean_tibble <- json_data %>%
      get_tibble(pluck = c("Leagues", 1, "Events"), 
                 value = "data")
```

Comment: Can you show a small reproducible example

Comment: Tried to rough in an example. Obviously didn't build a full dataset but hopefully the problem is clear.

Comment: In the first example that you mentioned as This Works, I get a NULL `list`.  Is that your expected

Comment: Yeah Im just trying to pluck that level

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can pass the arguments as a `list` instead of vector because vector can have only a single type

```
get_tibble <- function(data, pluck_value, name = NULL, value = "value")  {
           data %>% 
             pluck(!!! pluck_value) %>%
             enframe(name = NULL, value = "data")
            }



json_data %>%
  get_tibble(pluck_value = list("Leagues", 1, "Events"), 
             value = "data")
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 1 x 1
#  data  
#  <list>
#1 <NULL>
```

NOTE: It is also better to have input arguments different name than the function name e.g. `pluck`

When we do

```
c("Leagues", 1, "Events")
#[1] "Leagues" "1"       "Events"
```

Note the `1` is not integer, it is a `character` and this create one issue as it will check for the element with the name `1` instead of extracting the first element